# Use vs. misuse of generic algorithms

Tags: c++, c++11, stl-algorithm

To make the discussion concrete, suppose a simple example problem: the user enters several one-digit numbers without spaces, presses `Enter` and gets the sum of these numbers. So, a user session can look like this:

```
> 1231
7
> 12
3
> 0123
6
> ^D
```

I am learning C++ by going through the **C++ Primer** (5th edition). Before learning Chapter 10 on generic algorithms, I would solve the above problem in the following naive way:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "> ";
    std::string word;
    while (std::cin >> word) {
        auto sum = 0;
        for (auto c : word) sum += c - '0';
        std::cout << sum << std::endl << "> ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is how I solved the same problem armed with generic algorithms:

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "> ";
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> in(std::cin), eof;
    std::for_each(in, eof,
                  [](const std::string &word) {
                      std::cout << std::accumulate
                          (word.cbegin(), word.cend(), 0,
                           [](int cur, char ch) {
                               return cur + (ch - '0');
                           }) << std::endl << "> ";
                  });
    return 0;
}
```

To tell you the truth, I like the first solution much more. It's short and easy to read. The second solution sacrifices both brevity and clarity on the altar of the C++11's standard library.

My question is three-fold:

1. Am I correct in my comparison of the two solutions?
2. Is there a better way to solve the example problem by using the standard library's capabilities?
3. If the naive solution is actually the best one in this case, then what are the real use cases for the capabilities of the C++11's standard library that I used in the example?

---

EDIT: Actually, I should have gone all the way with the I/O iterators. After cleaning it up a little, this is what I got. Any comments?

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "> ";
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> in(std::cin), eof;
    std::ostream_iterator<int> out(std::cout, "\n> ");
    using CStrR = const std::string &;
    auto myAdd = [](int acc, char ch) {return acc + (ch - '0');};
    auto mySum = [&](CStrR word) {
        out = std::accumulate(word.cbegin(), word.cend(), 0, myAdd);
    };
    std::for_each(in, eof, mySum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think a `reduce` algorithm (Elements of Programming) would make more sense here than an `accumulate` algorithm due to the need of interpreting characters as integers. `reduce` takes a unary function and a binary operation. Something like `reduce(cbegin(word), cend(word), plus<>{}, charToInt{})`, or using a range-interface `reduce(word, plus<>{}, charToInt{})` But I don't think that improves upon the "basic" solution.

Comment: @dyp What is **Elements of Programming**?

Comment: I also like you first solution better. However, you are using generic algorithms to add up integers, so it actually is misuse of generic capabilities. However, if you wanted to write a program that can add up integers as well as floats as well as complex, I am pretty sure you are better off with a generic solution

Comment: @tobi303 Then I could make a template function out of my basic approach.

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg A book by the STL inventor Alexander Stepanov and Paul McJones. It is some kind of introduction to generic programming, but it also more than just that.

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg yes you could. templates = generic

Comment: Thinking a bit more about it, this looks like some `reduce_while` algorithm: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e391d0eeacf1485b

Comment: @dyp Is there such a thing in the standard library?

Comment: @MeirGoldenberg No. The Standard Library is not very large, and most real-world C++ programs use 3rd party libraries to provide additional functionality or convenience.

Comment: @dyp So, is this code part of a library? Could you please provide a link to the library's home page?

Comment: I do not know any library this is part of. Feel free to start one :) (google shows only a single result for *C++ "reduce_while"*.. but it might have another name of course)

Answer (score 2):

You could write simpler. For example

```
auto sum = std::accumulate( std::istream_iterator<char>( std::cin ), 
                            std::istream_iterator<char>(),
                            0, []( auto acc, auto c ) { return acc += c -'0'; } ); 

std::cout << sum << std::endl;
```

Or

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "> ";

    std::string word;

    while ( std::cin >> word ) 
    {
        auto sum = std::accumulate( word.begin(), word.end(), 0, 
                                    []( int acc, char c ) { return acc += c - '0'; } );
        std::cout << sum << std::endl << "> ";
    }
}
```

Though sometimes it is indeed better to use ordinary loops instead of compound algorithm records.:)

Comment: The first snippet does not solve the same problem, does it? It works for only one sum (I had the outer `for_each` to loop over words). Also, `std::istream_iterator<char>()` matches EOF, not the end of the current word doesn't it?

Comment: @Meir Goldenberg In this case you can use std::istringstream_iterator. The call of the algorithm will look the same way.

Comment: "Though **sometimes** it is indeed better to use ordinary loops instead of compound algorithm records". Do you include the current example into "sometimes"? Could you please qualify this word?

Comment: @Meir Goldenberg Relative to this particular example I would use std::accumulate as I showed. However sometimes the code looks not so clear and it is better to use loops. For example sometimes instead of algorithm std::for_each it is better to use the range based for loop provided that the whole range is used.

Comment: @Meir Goldenberg  Splitting a compound expression into more simple expressions make the code more readable.

Comment: What would you say about the code snippet in the EDIT at the end of the question?

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that this just a toy example to make it simpler to understand some complex concepts. You'll likely not see code this simple in practice.

You should never* sacrifice the clarity of the code. While computers become faster, new standard appear, new coding styles are suggested, the code you wrote doesn't become easier to read, understand or debug.

So for this particular problem the shorter version is likely what you want.
If for example you want to support cin but also vectors of characters, then the second version is more appropriate as you have to make less changes, but you could also modify the first one.

Always look at what's appropriate for the problem at hand, keep it simple, and don't be afraid to modify your project's code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is less that the general approach is wrong, and more that the C++ stdlib in general is well-known to be over-verbose. The Committee is working on real ranges which would make this a good deal simpler, but they're not done yet.

A good chunk is also the completely unnecessary newlines and related indentation sins.

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "> ";
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> in(std::cin), eof;
    std::ostream_iterator<int> out(std::cout, "\n> ");
    std::for_each(in, eof, [&out](std::string word) {
        *out = std::accumulate(word.begin(), word.end(), 0, [](int cur, char ch) {
            return cur + (ch - '0');
        });
    });
    return 0;
}
```

If you format it in a reasonable way, it's a lot more competitive.

Besides, ultimately, the algorithms library is not built for solving trivial problems, it's built for solving hard problems.